# nao/pepper soft-bank html

Tags: html, nao-robot, pepper

hi I have a pepper from Softbank

---

and I can't figure out how to send a string from pepper behavior to a HTML page. dos anybody now wat API or what method pepper can send a string to a HTML page that is showing on pepper tablet.

HTML is in pepper behavior and is running on the tablet of pepper
behavior need send just a string of info
and HTML page on pepper need to catch it

## html script

```
function yourMethod(data) {
var a = angular.fromJson(data);
var weekday = new Array(7);
console.log(str(data));
console.log('test1');


window.addEventListener("message", yourMethod, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the naoqi sdk you can find a "qimessaging.js" file(/var/www/libs/qimessaging/1.0/qimessaging.js)  that helps you connect a webpage (running on the tablet) to the head of pepper.

You use these functionalities by adding the following line to the head of your html script:

```
<script src="/libs/qimessaging/1.0/qimessaging.js"></script>
```

You can also find a complete tutorial here:
http://protolab.aldebaran.com:9000/protolab/tutorials/tree/master/ConnectionHtmlChoregraphe